# SQL server data integrity of blobs copied with INSERT INTO SELECT

Tags: sql-server

I'm copying some blob fields between 2 databases (SQL server 2008) for a documents migration, using the "INSERT INTO SELECT" bulk import SQL command.

I couldn't find out if there is a risk of the data being corrupted during the transfer, or if SQL server handles integrity.

I would like to avoid having to check each blob with a hash as this takes a long time to process (using a function based on Hashbytes) for a volume of data above 50gb.

Thank you, Ben

Comment: so you want to do insert into table1 select from table2 where both tables are in a different database ? Why do you think there is a change of data getting corrupt ?

Comment: @GuidoG Yes that's correct. I don't know if there is a risk, that's why I'm asking!